# Spring Data JPA dynamic projection with Paging

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We have a repository where we would like to use a dynamic projection with a paging:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    @Query("select p from Person p")
    <T> Page<T> dynamicInterfaceProjection(final Class<T> projectionClass, final Pageable pageable);
}
```

But when we call it, we get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter position: 1
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.getBinding(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.11.Final.jar:5.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:503) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.11.Final.jar:5.2.11.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.setParameter(AbstractProducedQuery.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.11.Final.jar:5.2.11.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:141) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQueryParameterBinder.bind(StringQueryParameterBinder.java:61) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Obviously, Spring Data JPA doesn't recognize the second **Pageable** parameter. Switching parameters order results in the same exception.

Are we doing something wrong? Is this even supported?

Comment: In my tests Paged, Optional and Streamed dynamic projections are not working: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1185

Comment: Great, so we're waiting for a fix soon

Answer (score 1):

something like this worked for me using `findByIn`:

```
/**
 * @description -  gives dynamic projection  of the entity CarrotEntity,
 * based on the provided projection type.
 */

<T> Page<T> findByCarrotIdIn(Set<String> carrotIds, Class<T> type, Pageable pagable);
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, a Spring-Data-JPA Enthusiast has created a project that implements projections with specifications. I am using it in my own project without problem. You may check it from here:

https://github.com/pramoth/specification-with-projection